# How to use the same pipeline in different environments with varying number of customers inside Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I have a copy data pipeline in the Azure Data Factory. I need to deploy the same Data Factory instance in multiple environments like DEV, QA, PROD using Release Pipeline.

The pipeline transfer data from **Customer Storage Account (Blob Container)** to **Centralized Data Lake**. So, we can say - its a Many to One flow. *(Many customers > One Data Lake)*

Now, suppose I am in DEV environment & I have 1 demo customer there. I have defined an ADF pipeline for Copy Data. But in prod environment, the number of customers will grow. So, I don't want to create multiple copies of the same pipeline in production Data Factory.

I am looking out for a solution so that I can keep one copy pipeline in Data Factory and deploy/promote the same Data Factory from one environment to the other environment. And this should work even if the number of customers is varying from one to another.

I am also doing CI/CD in Azure Data Factory using Git integration with Azure Repos.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create additional linked services and datasets which do not exist in a non-production environment to ensure any new "customer" storage account is mapped to the pipeline instance.

With CI/CD routines, you can deliver this in an incremental manner i.e. parameterize you release pipeline with variable groups and update the data factory instance with newer pipelines with new datasets/linked services.

Comment: Slide no. 48 here...I was exactly looking for - https://www.slideshare.net/CathrineWilhelmsen/building-dynamic-pipelines-in-azure-data-factory-sqlsaturday-oslo